# php incrementing grades in a file

Tags: php

I am new to php and I am trying to do the following task. I fill I am doing it the longer way. even, it is not working. Can any one help, recommend an easy way of doing it? thank you! 
**Task** 
Your task is to write a PHP script that reads grades from the file grades.txt, increments the grades by one and writes the incremented
grades to the file results.txt and finally prints the grades from results.txt. If the grade is five, it won't be incremented. The grades in
grades.txt are each in its own row and the amount of digits in a grade may vary. The grades are between 0-5. The grades written in
results.txt should each also be in their own rows.
 **Example output**

```
New grades:  
3  
5  
2  
1  
5  
3  
5  
5  
3  
3  
5  
4
```

**my code:**

```
<?php  
$fileName1="grades.txt";  
$fp = fopen($fileName1, "r");  
$i=0  
while(!feof($fp)&& fgets($fp)<5){  
$Grades[$i+1]=fgets($fp);  
$i++  
}  
fclose($fp);  
$fileName2="results.txt";  
$fr = fopen($fileName2, "w");  
fwrite($fr,$Grades[$i]."\n");   
$file_handle = fopen("results.txt", "r");  
while (!feof($file_handle)) {  
   $line = fgets($file_handle);  
   echo "New grades:\n"  
   echo $line;  
}  
fclose($file_handle);  
?>
```

Comment: What is the Example Input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write something simple like this ?

```
<?php
$incr = array();
foreach(file('grades.txt') as $v) # Opening the file and looping through the values
{
    if($v==5){$incr[]=$v;} # If grade is greater than 5 , dont increment
    else{
        $incr[]=$v+1;
    }
}
//array_walk($incr,function(&$v){ $v=trim($v);});
$incr = array_map('trim',$incr);
$str = implode(PHP_EOL,$incr); # Implodes the array with PHP_EOL
file_put_contents('results.txt',$str); # Writes to the file

#Displaying from results...

foreach(file('results.txt') as $v) # Opening the new file and displaying the results
{
    echo $v."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I am only allowed to do it in php read and write file handling methods but your method is also cool! when I tried your method it is printing two empty rows. why is that?

Comment: Hi it should work now perfectly. Can you try now ? Btw these methods are also meant to handle files.

Comment: It is saying: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in .php on line 10

Errors parsing .php on "array_walk($incr,function(&$v){ $v=trim($v);});"

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly mate. Ok can you replace that line with `$incr = array_map('trim',$incr);` as shown in the answer.

Comment: Hi, one last Q. the program which checks my code is not reading the last digit "4" in this case. why do you think it is?

Comment: Can you post the file in the question ?

Comment: It is not my file. It is system generated file. are you familiar with viope.com It is a self study environment. So I can't see or change the file.